# Call an android layout in another one to make a nested layout

Tags: android, android-layout

Sorry I am new in Android

Because of my large contents I am going to create a `ScrollView`. In this way, I have created some parts of my content in 1 file (let's call it **FirstLayout.xml**) and the other part  **SeconedLayout.xml**. Now I am going to call both of them in a single **XML** file.(**Parent.xml**)

But the problem is, I don't know, how should I call them in my **ScrollView**?

here is the code

FirstLayout.xml

```
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
.
.
.
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

SeconedLayout.xml is:

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
  ...
    </LinearLayout>
```

Parent.xml

visible

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroller"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

<!-- Call FirstLayout  -->  


<!-- Call SecondLayout  -->
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: use the <include layout="@layout/titlebar"/> like this

Comment: Use `<include />` tag

Comment: You need to include run time or previous time...

Comment: `AbsoluteLayout` ===> Are you kidding? FYI, its deprecated. Yes you should use if you are developing app for only and only one screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can include layout like

```
<include layout="@layout/FirstLayout" />

<include layout="@layout/SeconedLayout" />
```

so your layout should be like

```
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/scroller"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true" >
     <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    <include layout="@layout/FirstLayout" />

    <include layout="@layout/SeconedLayout" />
  </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: I did it, but it gives me the error which says:_"The ScrollView can only support one layout"_ So i put all them in a _LinearLayout_ and not just the first layout is shown??!!!

Answer (score 2):

You should use include tag:

```
<include 
    layout="@layout/SeconedLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use include tag, e.g

```
<include layout="@layout/firstlayout" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try just to use the include tag like that :

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroller"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >
<include layout="@layout/FirstLayout" />
<include layout="@layout/SeconedLayout" />
</ScrollView>
```

But for better performance, use the  tag, that helps eliminate redundant view groups in your view hierarchy when including one layout within another. Get a look [here](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html).